# How to add camera interface in gvractivity?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, google-vr

Can any one give a simple explanation or program for `gvractivty` and camera in Android, because `gvrview` use `eglconfig` as a parameter but camera needs surface holder.

So, how to change it? I am not able to configure it out and also it requires to implement `surfacecall` in camera so how to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this repo [CardboardPassthrough](https://github.com/Sveder/CardboardPassthrough), would be a good start.